# Restrictions on Twilio trial account for receiving SMS?

Tags: sms, twilio

I have a Twilio trial account, and I've been testing a web app for receiving SMS.  I've assigned a URL for the inbound SMS messages, and that's been working fine.  So far I haven't encountered any limitations on how many SMS messages I can receive, how fast, or anything like that.  I didn't find anything on the Twilio website about this, either.

What is the limit, if anything, that my trial account has on receiving SMS messages?  I don't need to send a response to the SMS sender, so I'm not worried about the cost to send SMS, or the "Sent by Twilio" that gets appended to a sent SMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some information from Twilio's Twitter (dates back to March 27, 2014): https://twitter.com/twilio/status/449231807888621568

"There is no time limit, you can go at your own pace (unless you outpace $30) . More free trial info: http://bit.ly/1fo64aN"

You can check your current balance here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/usage/primary